# MPMoviePlayerController producing blink between consecutive video

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video

After completion of first video and starting of second video - after changing the content url 
, MPMoviePlayerController  producing black blink.

Any one suggest the solution to play consecutively video in iPhone ?

Comment: it's just because MPMoviePlayerController finishes and re starts with another URL so it should happen and it's happening there is no way out.

Comment: @eptdeveloper: You should prbably remake your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's just because MPMoviePlayerController finishes and re-starts with another URL so it should happen and it's happening there is no way out.